# Converting a tbl_df to a list of ts (Time-series)

Tags: r, time-series, tibble

Is there a way to convert this tbl_df (`df_ex`) to a list of ts (like this one: `list_ts_ex`)?

Data for `df_ex`:

```
library(OECD)

dataset <- "MEI"
filter_list <- list("", "LORSGPNO", "STSA", "M")
df_ex <- get_dataset(dataset = dataset, filter = filter_list)
```

I would like to achieve something similar to this (`list_ts_ex`):

```
library(BGVAR)

data(monthlyData)
list_ts_ex <- monthlyData
```

I can extract each country and create its own `ts`, like this:

```
BRLGDP <- subset(df, LOCATION == "BRA") %>%
  select(obsTime, obsValue)
colnames(BRLGDP) <- c("Date", "GDP")
BRLGDP$Date <- as.Date(as.yearmon(BRLGDP$Date, format = "%Y-%m"), frac = 1)
BRLGDP_ts <- ts(BRLGDP[-1], start = as.yearmon(BRLGDP$Date[1]), frequency = 12)
```

Later I could put them all together to create the list of time-series objects. Nevertheless, I think there are more efficient ways to do so. I just cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer myself:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df_ex <- df_ex %>% 
  split(.$LOCATION) %>% 
  lapply(function(.x) ts(zoo(.x$obsValue, .x$obsTime), start = c(2020, 1), frequency = 12))
```

This may be helpful for someone else.